# Error compiling gem 'sqlite3' ruby project

Tags: database, sqlite

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and I want to start a new project on Ruby on Rails, but I'm encountering some issues with sqlite3 gem. This is my error, how can I fix?? Thank you. I'm running Ruby 2.5.1 and Rails 2.5.2

```
Fetching sqlite3 1.4.2
Installing sqlite3 1.4.2 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/home/pgreco/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2/ext/sqlite3
/home/pgreco/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby -r
./siteconf20200131-10946-1ee4o20.rb extconf.rb
checking for sqlite3.h... no
sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'brew install sqlite3',
'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
and check your shared library search path (the
location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/home/pgreco/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
--with-sqlcipher
--without-sqlcipher
--with-sqlite3-config
--without-sqlite3-config
--with-pkg-config
--without-pkg-config
--with-sqlcipher
--without-sqlcipher
--with-sqlite3-dir
--without-sqlite3-dir
--with-sqlite3-include
--without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
--with-sqlite3-lib
--without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib

 To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
 be found here:

/home/pgreco/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0            /sqlite3-1.4.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
 /home/pgreco/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sqlite3-1.4.2 for
   inspection.
  Results logged to
 /home/pgreco/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0                               /sqlite3-1.4.2/gem_make.out

 An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.4.2), and Bundler cannot
 continue.
 Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
 succeeds before bundling.

 In Gemfile:
     sqlite3
     run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
 Could not find gem 'sqlite3' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
 Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I'm running sqlite3 but I tried even to set pg as default db but there is the same error

Comment: Read closer - `sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'brew install sqlite3',
'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'` is in there. You need SQLite installed to build the gem.

Comment: Yeeeeeeeeee, welcome to rails :P it works, thank you!